# Stata .do file execution by CMD, but fail due to accented characters in the path

Tags: batch-file, cmd, stata

I am trying to run a Stata do file from windows command line but it doesn't execute as the directory name contains space and accented characters. Unfortunately, I can't rename the directory as it is a corporate standard.

You can see the command here:

```
cmd

"T:/Stata14/StataMp-64.exe" /e do "Y:/do/mydofile.do"
```

The "mydofile.do" contains the following simple code:

```
clear

set more off

sysuse auto

save "Y:/állé test/test.dta"
```

The script is working perfectly fine using Stata GUI, but Windows seems to be more sensitive to special characters (If I change the save location to "Y:/alle_test/test.dta" also works, but as I said it is prohibited).

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: What is the output of the command `CHCP`. Does stata expect OEM or ANSI character encoding?

Comment: CHCP: 852. I think stata uses ANSI but I’m not sure

Comment: Thx for the hint! Unfortunately, there are no short names attached to my directories. I’m going to ask the admin to set it up. Then i give a feedback